# How to break a line in VB6

Tags: sql, vb6, line-breaks

I need to break this line of code but i do not know how:

```
sql = "select [ID], [First Name], [Last Name], [Mark 1 ENG], [Mark 2 ENG], [Mark 3 ENG], [Mark 1 MAT], [Mark 2 MAT], [Mark 3 MAT], [Mark 1 SCI], [Mark 2 SCI], [Mark 3 SCI] from Table1 where [Active] <> 'No'"
```

This is what i mean when i say break:

```
    If txtFirstName.Text = "" Or txtLastName.Text = "" Or txtMarks(0).Text = "" Or txtMarks(1).Text = "" Or txtMarks(2).Text = "" _
    Or txtMarks(3).Text = "" Or txtMarks(4).Text = "" Or txtMarks(5).Text = "" Or txtMarks(6).Text = "" Or txtMarks(7).Text = "" _
    Or txtMarks(8).Text = "" Then
```

Where do i put the underscores in this line because wherever i put them it gives me an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to split up the string via concatenation:

```
sql = "select [ID], [First Name], [Last Name], [Mark 1 ENG], [Mark 2 ENG], " & _
     "[Mark 3 ENG], [Mark 1 MAT], [Mark 2 MAT], [Mark 3 MAT], [Mark 1 SCI], " & _
     "[Mark 2 SCI], [Mark 3 SCI] from Table1 where [Active] <> 'No'"
```